# proper way to format the date depending on scenario

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, date-fns

I have a scenario where I can have a date coming as a string. It can be formatted as either:

2021-05-29

29-05-2021

Im using dateFns to parse the strings, but when the string is in the format 2021-05-29, it cant parse the string, which is why, when it has the format of 2021-05-29, it needs to be converted into 29-05-2021...

The parse() function from dateFns what actually what I needed to parse it to the correct format, but it doenst seem to work when passing 2021-05-29

```
return parse(date, 'mm-dd-yyyy', new Date());
```

Any ideas what how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reversing the date,

```
date = date.split(“-“).reverse().join(“-“)
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to i ONLY do it for those cases where I get the date in the wrong format? I dont want to do it for the right formatted dates...

Comment: You could check whether date.charAt(2)==‘-‘